# Unable to install a Map Tile Server on Raspberry Pi

Tags: debian, node.js, sqlite

**I have a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ running Raspbian**

uname -a

```
Linux raspberrypi 4.14.98-v7+ #1200 SMP Tue Feb 12 20:27:48 GMT 2019 armv7l
```

cat /etc/os-release

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

**I am currently running a web server using nodejs on my raspberry pi but also need to run a map tile server as well.**

**When I try to run docker containers of tileserver-gl or openmaptiles-server i get the same error.**

sudo docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/data -p 8080:80 klokantech/openmaptiles-server

sudo docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/data -p 8080:80 klokantech/tileserver-gl

```
standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

**When I try to install a tile server using node/npm, it also fails.**

node -v

```
v10.15.3
```

sudo npm install -g tileserver-gl

```
/usr/bin/tileserver-gl -> /usr/lib/node_modules/tileserver-gl/src/main.js

> sqlite3@4.0.6 install /usr/lib/node_modules/tileserver-gl/node_modules/sqlite3
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for sqlite3@4.0.6 and node@10.15.3 (node-v64 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/tileserver-gl/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding'
gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/root/.node-gyp/10.15.3"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/lib/node_modules/tileserver-gl/node_modules/sqlite3/.node-gyp"
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/tileserver-gl/node_modules/sqlite3/.node-gyp'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.14.98-v7+
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/usr/lib/node_modules/tileserver-gl/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v64-linux-arm/node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=/usr/lib/node_modules/tileserver-gl/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v64-linux-arm" "--napi_version=3" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v64"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/lib/node_modules/tileserver-gl/node_modules/sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/lib/node_modules/tileserver-gl/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v64-linux-arm/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/usr/lib/node_modules/tileserver-gl/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v64-linux-arm --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v64' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/tileserver-gl/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.14.98-v7+
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/tileserver-gl/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /usr/lib/node_modules/tileserver-gl/node_modules/sqlite3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/lib/node_modules/tileserver-gl/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v64-linux-arm/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/usr/lib/node_modules/tileserver-gl/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v64-linux-arm --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v64' (1)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sqlite3@4.0.6 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@4.0.6 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-04-02T19_28_13_489Z-debug.log
```

**I get a similar error when I try to install other node map tile servers from npm...**

Comment: You have a couple of `permission denied` errors - which is odd when using `sudo`

Comment: It looks like the developers of openmaptiles-server and tileserver-gl haven't added support for ARM yet. I was able to install python TileStache but in the end I found a python3 Map Tile Downloader https://github.com/AliFlux/MapTilesDownloader and decided to use that instead since it easily integrates with my Leaflet client-side setup.

Comment: Try: sudo npm install -g tileserver-gl --unsafe-perm